# Not getting expected debug print from program that opens and writes a file

Tags: c

I am learning about file descriptors by using the `open`, `write` and `close` functions. What I expect is a `printf` statement outputting the file descriptor after the `open` function, and another `printf` statement outputting a confirmation of the text being written. However, I get the following result:

```
.\File.exe "this is a test"
[DEBUG] buffer   @ 0x00b815c8: 'this is a test'
[DEBUG] datafile  @ 0x00b81638: 'C:\Users\____\Documents\Notes'
```

With a blank space where the further debugging output should be. The code block for the section is:

```
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]); //copy first vector into the buffer
    
    printf("[DEBUG] buffer \t @ 0x%08x: \'%s\'\n", buffer, buffer); //debug buffer 
    printf("[DEBUG] datafile  @ 0x%08x: \'%s\'\n", datafile, datafile); //debug datafile 
    
    strncat(buffer, "\n", 1); //adds a newline

    fd = open(datafile, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR); //opens file
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        fatal("in main() while opening file");
    }
    printf("[DEBUG] file descriptor is %d\n", fd);
    
    if(write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) == -1) //wrting data
    {
        fatal("in main() while writing buffer to file");
    }
    
    if(close(fd) == -1) //closing file
    {
        fatal("in main() while closing file");
    }
    
    printf("Note has been saved.");
```

I basically copied the code word for word from the book I'm studying, so how could it not work?

The problem is that the `printf` function does not display anything, and the file descriptor is not returned.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void usage(char *pnt, char *opnt) //usage function
{
    printf("Usage: %s <data to add to \"%s\">", pnt, opnt);
    exit(0);
}

void fatal(char*); //fatal function for errors
void *ec_malloc(unsigned int); //wrapper for malloc error checking

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //initiates argumemt vector/count variables
{
    int fd; //file descriptor
    char *buffer, *datafile;
    
    buffer = (char*) ec_malloc(100); //buffer given 100 bytes of ec memory
    datafile = (char*) ec_malloc(20); //datafile given 20 bytes of ec memory
    strcpy(datafile, "C:\\Users\\____\\Documents\\Notes");
    
    if(argc < 2) //if argument count is less than 2 i.e. no arguments provided
    {
        usage(argv[0], datafile); //print usage message from usage function 
    }
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]); //copy first vector into the buffer
    
    printf("[DEBUG] buffer \t @ %p: \'%s\'\n", buffer, buffer); //debug buffer 
    printf("[DEBUG] datafile  @ %p: \'%s\'\n", datafile, datafile); //debug datafile 
    
    strncat(buffer, "\n", 1); //adds a newline
    
    fd = open(datafile, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR); //opens file
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        fatal("in main() while opening file");
    }
    printf("[DEBUG] file descriptor is %d\n", fd);
    
    if(write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) == -1) //wrting data
    {
        fatal("in main() while writing buffer to file");
    }
    
    if(close(fd) == -1) //closing file
    {
        fatal("in main() while closing file");
    }
    
    printf("Note has been saved."); 
    
    free(buffer);
    free(datafile);
}

void fatal(char *message)
{
    char error_message[100];
    strcpy(error_message, "[!!] Fatal Error ");
    strncat(error_message, message, 83);
    perror(error_message);
    exit(-1);
}

void *ec_malloc(unsigned int size)
{
    void *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(size);
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        fatal("in ec_malloc() on memory allocation");
        return ptr;
    }
}
```

EDIT: the issue has been fixed. The reason for this bug was that the memory allocated within the `ec_malloc` function was not sufficient, which meant that the text could not be saved. I changed the byte value to 100 and the code now works.

Comment: stderr is intended for error reporting.

Comment: (I do think there's rarely any justification for using `strcat()`/`strncat()`... there's almost always more efficient and/or safer ways to build up a string. `snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s\n", argv[1]);` for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure which compiler you are using, but the one I tried the code with (GCC) says:

```
main.c:34:5: warning: ‘strncat’ specified bound 1 equals source length [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   34 |     strncat(buffer, "\n", 1); //adds a newline
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In other words, the call to `strncat` in your code is highly suspicious. You are trying to append a single line-break character, which has a length of 1, which you pass as the third argument. But `strncat` expects the third parameter to be the remaining space in `buffer`, not the length of the string to append.

A correct call would look a bit like this:

```c
size_t bufferLength = 100;
char* buffer = malloc(bufferLength);

strncat(buffer, "\n", (bufferLength - strlen(buffer) - strlen("\n") - 1));
```

In this case, however, you are saved, because `strncat` guarantees that the resulting buffer is NUL-terminated, meaning that it always writes one additional byte beyond the specified size.

All of this is complicated, and a common source of bugs. It's easier to simply use `snprintf` to build up the entire string at one go:

```c
size_t bufferLength = 100;
char* buffer = malloc(bufferLength);

snprintf(buffer, bufferLength, "%s\n", argv[1]);
```

---

Another bug in your code is the `ec_malloc` function:

```c
void *ec_malloc(unsigned int size)
{
    void *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(size);
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        fatal("in ec_malloc() on memory allocation");
        return ptr;
    }
}
```

See if you can spot it: what happens if `ptr` is *not* `NULL`? Well, nothing! The function doesn't return a value in this case; execution just falls off the end.

If you're using GCC (and possibly other compilers) on x86, this code will appear to work fine, because the result of the `malloc` function will remain in the proper CPU register to serve as the result of the `ec_malloc` function. But the fact that it just happens to work by the magic of circumstance does not make it correct code. It is subject to stop working at any time, and it should be fixed. The function deserves a return value!

Unfortunately, the GCC compiler is unable to detect this mistake, but Clang does:

```
<source>:64:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

---

The *major* bug in your code is a buffer overrun. At the top, you allocate only 20 bytes for the `datafile` buffer:

```c
datafile = (char*) ec_malloc(20); //datafile given 20 bytes of ec memory
```

which means it can only store 20 characters. However, you proceed to write in more than 20 characters:

```c
strcpy(datafile, "C:\\Users\\____\\Documents\\Notes");
```

That string literal is 33 characters, *not including* the terminating NUL! You need a buffer with at least 50 characters of space to hold all of this. With a buffer that is too small, the `strcpy` function call creates a classic "buffer overrun" error, which is undefined behavior that manifests itself as corrupting your program's memory area and thus premature termination.

Again, when I tried compiling and running the code, GCC reported:

```
malloc(): corrupted top size
```

because it detected that you had overrun the dynamically-allocated memory (returned by `malloc`). It was able to do this because, under the hood, `malloc` stores sentinel information *after* the allocated memory block, and your overwriting of the allocated space had written over its sentinel information.

---

The whole code is a bit suspect; it was not written by someone who knows C very well, nor was it debugged or reviewed by anyone else.

There is no real need to use dynamic memory allocation here in order to allocate fixed-size buffers. If you're going to use dynamic memory allocation, then allocate the actual amount of space that you need. Otherwise, if you're allocating fixed-size buffers, then just allocate on the stack.

Don't bother with complex string-manipulation functions when you can get away with simply using `snprintf`.

And as a bonus tip: when debugging problems, try to reduce the code down as small as you can get it. None of the file I/O stuff was related to this problem, so when I was analyzing this code, I replaced that whole section with:

```c
printf("[DEBUG] file descriptor is %d\n", 42);
```

Once the rest of the code is working, I can go back and add the real code back to that section, and then test it. (Which I didn't do, because I don't have a file system handy to test this.)